# I get this error while trying to launch the command ./runInstaller

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, redhat

I have this error while trying to launch the command ./runInstaller
Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: DISPLAY is some ip address of where the screen has to be displayed? I used it with humming bird exceed.

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle help docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E89497_01/html/rpm_80_installation/GUID-842C3883-9BC1-4D37-82C1-9E7F24628AA7.htm):

```
sudo yum install xorg-x11-utils -y
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing this via Putty, then I suggest you have a look at Xming, this allows you to have a Putty remote ssh session, and forward your display to you Windows machine...

If you're executing this from a Linux server without a gui, you will either need to connect remotely with a pc with a GUI installed (Gnome, KDE, etc) or you'll need to install the Gui directly on the server.

Check if it's not already installed by using the command on the terminal 
$ startx

Comment: what did you mean by putty and how can i use it

Answer (score 0):

Error is reproducible thus:

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0
$ ./runInstaller
ERROR: Unable to verify the graphical display setup. This application requires X display. Make sure that xdpyinfo exist under PATH variable.

Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

OP's X server was Hummingbird Exceed. Xming will work as well.

The actual solution depends on:

- whether you are su'd to oracle from a different login account.
- whether you are using X11 forwarding.
- the actual port used by X11 forwarding, which could be 6010 or a different port.

If you logged in and then su'd to oracle, then copy ~/.Xauthority to the oracle account.

If you are using X11 forwarding and the forwarding port is 6010, then DISPLAY=localhost:10.0 is correct.

If you are not using X11 forwarding, and if port 6000 on your PC is reachable from the oracle server, then export DISPLAY=your.pc.ip.address:0.0 is correct.

Install xterm and use xterm to test X windows.

Be sure to install xdpyinfo.

For more details, please refer to my article [X windows for Oracle DBAs](https://exagriddba.wordpress.com/2019/08/12/x-windows-for-oracle-dbas/)